# How to go up or down with helicopter in fortnite on Mac?

Tags: macos, fortnite-battle-royale

I can't find controls to elevate when flying with helicopter. I googled it without any luck. How to elevate and land on MacOs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It defaults to Left Mouse Button or Right Mouse Button. You can double check in the Controls.

Comment: thank you, i was looking only keyboard ) mouse click doesn't come to mind, it's usually for shooting )